# Interpreting the summaries of survival models with different distributions (flexsurvreg R package)

Tags: survival, mortality

I run several [flexsurvreg](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flexsurv/versions/2.0/topics/flexsurvreg) models with the same predictors and now struggle to interpret their findings in an understandable plain language. Males seem to have lower survival in all models, but the numbers differ.

Distributions' outputs are described here [flexsurvreg](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flexsurv/versions/2.0/topics/flexsurvreg). What is the difference between mu, scale, log, rate?

Also, which of these distributions has to meet the proportional hazards assumption?

**Model**

The aim is to describe the age-adjusted survival of males compared to females. Both have 1-year follow up for survival.

```
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(time_12m, status_12m) ~ sex + age, 
data = data, dist = "*i used different distributions, given subsequently*")
```

**Exponential**

```
    data mean   est         L95%        U95%        se          exp(est)    L95%        U95%      
rate          NA   0.0001083   0.0000766   0.0001530   0.0000191          NA          NA          NA
sexm   0.2824819   0.5245623   0.4472475   0.6018772   0.0394471   1.6897192   1.5640014   1.8255424
```

**Weibull**

```
       data mean     est           L95%          U95%          se            exp(est)      L95%          U95%        
shape            NA       0.61315       0.59451       0.63237       0.00966            NA            NA            NA
scale            NA  398425.67126  211707.99966  749820.58200  128537.93805            NA            NA            NA
sexm        0.28248      -0.79826      -0.92584      -0.67068       0.06509       0.45011       0.39620       0.51136
age        78.78166      -0.10659      -0.11375      -0.09943       0.00365       0.89889       0.89248       0.90535
```

**Gamma**

```
       data mean     est           L95%          U95%          se            exp(est)      L95%          U95%        
shape            NA   0.577827877   0.557537956   0.598856188   0.010538315            NA            NA            NA
rate             NA   0.000002617   0.000001414   0.000004842   0.000000822            NA            NA            NA
sexm    0.282481942   0.731621654   0.613553046   0.849690262   0.060240193   2.078448400   1.846982167   2.338922286
age    78.781655208   0.099345162   0.092633836   0.106056489   0.003424209   1.104447447   1.097059957   1.111884684
```

**Gengamma**

```
       data mean  est      L95%     U95%     se       exp(est)  L95%     U95%   
mu          NA    12.3055  11.6896  12.9213   0.3142       NA        NA       NA
sigma       NA     2.8587   2.7300   2.9935   0.0672       NA        NA       NA
Q           NA    -0.3773  -0.5381  -0.2166   0.0820       NA        NA       NA
sexm    0.2825    -0.8321  -0.9751  -0.6890   0.0730   0.4351    0.3772   0.5021
age    78.7817    -0.1075  -0.1144  -0.1007   0.0035   0.8981    0.8919   0.9042
```

**Gengamma.orig**

```
       data mean     est           L95%          U95%          se            exp(est)      L95%          U95%        
shape            NA   0.109857565   0.103497004   0.116609024   0.003342982            NA            NA            NA
scale            NA   0.000006421   0.000000509   0.000080941   0.000008302            NA            NA            NA
k                NA  15.205087703  13.581492863  17.022774623   0.876031175            NA            NA            NA
sexm    0.282481942  -0.839859420  -0.977204430  -0.702514411   0.070075272   0.431771218   0.376361775   0.495338253
age    78.781655208  -0.108899371  -0.115913060  -0.101885681   0.003578479   0.896820659   0.890552644   0.903132791
```

**Genf**

```
       data mean  est       L95%      U95%      se        exp(est)  L95%      U95%    
mu           NA   11.73948  10.97629  12.50267   0.38939        NA        NA        NA
sigma        NA    2.67604   2.46050   2.91046   0.11465        NA        NA        NA
Q            NA   -0.96656  -1.43982  -0.49329   0.24147        NA        NA        NA
P            NA    0.67138   0.27689   1.62789   0.30340        NA        NA        NA
sexm    0.28248   -0.82946  -0.97312  -0.68580   0.07330   0.43629   0.37790   0.50369
age    78.78166   -0.10771  -0.11455  -0.10086   0.00349   0.89789   0.89176   0.90406
```

**Genf.orig gave NA-s, but in what scale are these estimates with this distribution?**

**Gompertz**

```
       data mean   est         L95%        U95%        se          exp(est)    L95%        U95%      
shape          NA  -0.2096535  -0.2210497  -0.1982573   0.0058145          NA          NA          NA
rate           NA   0.0004018   0.0002840   0.0005683   0.0000711          NA          NA          NA
sexm    0.2824819   0.4882750   0.4110692   0.5654808   0.0393915   1.6295029   1.5084297   1.7602940
age    78.7816552   0.0646473   0.0606360   0.0686585   0.0020466   1.0667827   1.0625121   1.0710704
```

**Llogis**

```
       data mean     est           L95%          U95%          se            exp(est)      L95%          U95%        
shape            NA       0.69953       0.67914       0.72053       0.01056            NA            NA            NA
scale            NA  357016.77325  191244.39796  666482.14397  113706.57349            NA            NA            NA
sexm        0.28248      -0.86755      -1.00463      -0.73048       0.06994       0.41998       0.36618       0.48168
age        78.78166      -0.11171      -0.11893      -0.10449       0.00368       0.89430       0.88787       0.90078
```

**Llnorm**

```
         data mean  est       L95%      U95%      se        exp(est)  L95%      U95%    
meanlog        NA   12.71115  12.11081  13.31150   0.30631        NA        NA        NA
sdlog          NA    2.57237   2.50385   2.64276   0.03543        NA        NA        NA
sexm      0.28248   -0.84678  -0.98701  -0.70654   0.07155   0.42879   0.37269   0.49335
age      78.78166   -0.10937  -0.11632  -0.10242   0.00355   0.89640   0.89019   0.90265
```